# Applying a function of several arguments to the rows of a matrix

Tags: functional-style, map

I have a user-defined function which takes three vectors as input. Suppose that is like this:

```
f[a_, b_, u_] := Total[a*Total[u]^b]
```

Usually I have vectors for `a` and `b` but a matrix format for `u`. For example,

```
a = {1.5, 2, 1}
b = {-1, 1, 0.5}
u = {{1, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1.5}, {2, 1, 1}}
```

which should give the result

> {8.23205, 7.18114, 10.375}

In other words, the function `f` should be applied to each row of `u`. I can do this using a `Do` loop, but I want to know how to do it using `Map` or other functional commands (but not `Table`).

Comment: Have a look at what `Total[a*Total[#]^b]&/@u` will do. In fact, take a look at the result of `Total[#]&/@u` to see what this syntax does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent to a `Do` loop using `Map` is

```
f[a, b, #] & /@ u
```

Which gives the desired results:

> {8.23205, 7.18114, 10.375}

Comment: It's nice. I was trying MAP[f[a,b,#],u] but it didn't work. I always got confused by pure functions!

Comment: @Amin You were very close! It can be written `Map[f[a, b, #] &, u]` -- remember that it's not a pure function until you've marked where it ends, with an ampersand. The highlighting will help you with this, the `#` will turn from pink to green once you have an `&` in place.

Answer (score 2):

[Anon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon)'s method is no doubt better but here is another method that may have some interest:

```
Block[{f, a, b}, Thread @ f[a, b, u]]
```

> ```
> {8.23205, 7.18114, 10.375}
> ```

This makes `f`, `a`, `b` effectively inert, then uses `Thread` to distribute across the rows of `u`.  This could also be formulated:

```
f @@@ Block[{a, b}, Thread@{a, b, u}]
```

You could also use `Outer`:

```
Outer[f, {a}, {b}, u, 1][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> {8.23205, 7.18114, 10.375}
> ```

Or a form of `Table`:

```
Table[f[a, b, x], {x, u}]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard. Those gave me another insights to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Anon's answer is the way I would do it, but it's fun to figure out a solution that works for single vectors as well as a list of vectors:

```
f[a_, b_, u_] := Map[Composition[#^b &, Total], u, {-2}].a
```

Examples

```
f[a, b, u]
```

> ```
> {8.23205, 7.18114, 10.375}
> ```

```
f[a, b, First@u]
```

> ```
> 8.23205
> ```